# Beginner Conditioning Question

Tags: storage, conditioning

Probably a stupid question, but.....
After I bottle and cap the beer do I store the beer in the fridge? Dark but No Fridge? I think I have done a decent job so far, and would hate to FUBAR everything up at this point!

If it helps the kit I purchased is for a Weizenbier....and when I said we did pretty good I mean that we only messed up and added both cans of LME to the boil at the same time instead of early in the boil and one during the last 15 mins. The maker of the kit said this it would just make a darker wheat bear but should be fine.

Comment: Well I finally got around to drinking a few (OK too many) of the beers... and thanks to the advice I have received here it turned out awesome! Very please with my work if I do say so myself!

Comment: By saying that there is no need to add the lme early in the boil do you mean wait till the end and dump it in? Not sure what you mean... the only complaint I have about this beer would be that its too dark.... just a cosmetic thing! I was hoping for a Boulevard Wheat Color or Goose Island 312 color.... it ended up like a BLUE MOON or Fat Tire, both good beers just darker than I like!

Answer (score 7):

You'll want to keep the bottles within the yeast's active temperature for the first week or so after bottling in order to keep the yeast active for carbonation. Most likely, that means room temperature. After that, you can chill the beer for drinking or to extend the lifetime (not that there's any rush, we're talking on the order of months).

Definitely keep it in a dark location to protect it from skunking.

Comment: Thanks for the info Greg... I am a teacher so it will be summer when its ready and I will not be in a rush. Once school starts again in the fall.... the lifetime of the beer will never be a problem!!!

Comment: I agree with Greg but suggest at least two weeks bottle conditioning at room temperature.

Answer (score 3):

just store it under the same conditions you fermented it in

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a minimum of 2 weeks at room temperature (not on a cold basement floor), and I personally let it sit for 3 weeks.  The yeast need time to ferment the sugar.  Giving them an extra week or two can't hurt, and helps improve the beer overall.

I also age my beer at room temperature for several weeks, and then put it in the fridge when ready to drink.

> > f it helps the kit I purchased is for a Weizenbier....and when I said we did pretty good I mean that we only messed up and added both cans of LME to the boil at the same time instead of early in the boil and one during the last 15 mins. The maker of the kit said this it would just make a darker wheat bear but should be fine.

There is no need to add the LME early in the boil, that only makes the beer darker.
It will not affect hop utilization either, thats determined by the volume of water.